# How to animate moving eyes and speaking mouth onto puppets in a stop-motion video?

Tags: rigging, image, tracking, effects

I’m very new to Blender, and I need to animate moving eyes and speaking mouth onto a stop-motion animation I’m making with puppets. I will shoot the video and then upload it into Blender to add these features afterwards. My understanding of Blender isn’t sophisticated enough to know the easiest way of doing this, does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you  want to do, if it's a stop motion with puppets, how do you use Blender?

Comment: @moonboots I will be shooting the video and then uploading it into Blender to then animate on top of it. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for VFX (visual effects). This requires camera tracking, focal length estimation, masking, and some modeling. This can be done in Blender but there are also add-ons like [Geotracker](https://keentools.io/products/geotracker-for-blender) that can help you with this process.